# Terminal issues on OS X with XAMPP and Yii framework

Tags: mac, terminal, xampp, mvc

I'm trying to configure the Yii framework but am having problems with the terminal commands, and am also having difficulty setting up the webapp demo. I am using Mac OS X Snow Leopard and have installed XAMPP and placed the 'yii' folder in the xamppfiles \ htdocs folder.

I have verified the http://localhost/yii/requirements/index.php which is working fine. I have tried the following but nothing seems to work so if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong it would be very much appreciated. In fact any directory I search for is not recognized (see below) so I'm thinking I need to do something else for this to work but I have searched and searched but found no answer.

```
~ Jake$ /applications/xampp/xamppfiles/yii
-bash: /applications/xampp/xamppfiles/yii: No such file or directory

~ Jake$ /documents
-bash: /documents: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error message is a different one if the file or folder actually exists, so missing the `cd` is *not* the issue here.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Are you following a tutorial, and if so, could you please tell us which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what you're trying to do, but the shell is not lying to you here: there is no such file, probably because you're looking in the wrong place. To find files that you're not sure of the exact path, you need to learn these methods:

1. Use `ls` to list files. Try typing `ls /Applications` to see if xampp is there. Then try `ls /Applications/xampp` and continue drilling down to what you need.
2. Type a partial path and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to try and auto-complete it:

   `/app`<kbd>Tab</kbd> → /Applications/

   If there's more than one match for what you typed, then it will show you a list of choices: just type more letters and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much,  I'll explain what I did in case anyone else needs it in the future.

I'm following a tutorial to configure Yii framework similar Zend.I could see the files and path using 'Finder' but couldn't do it via Terminal, I followed your 'ls' and 'Applications' appeared, I typed 'xa' but it only listed the dmg  which sits below the extracted file.I deleted all characters until only 'xampp' remained, then typed in partial letters for each of the folders and tabbed as you suggested and achieved what I wanted too.
thanks again.

Comment: Great! Please **upvote** if you found this answer helpful, and **accept** if it solved your problem.